# Attempting to create multiple child records from multi-value field

Tags: trigger, multi-select, childrecords

I am attempting to use a trigger to create a child record to an object (Policy_Profile__c) for each value in its Product_Affected3__c field. Each value represents a record in a 3rd object (Vendor_Product__c) and so in order to create a link to that record I am querying that record, getting a couple of its field values and placing it in the newly created child record.

THIS IS THE SOLUTION :

```
trigger AutoCreateSubsServOnContrOv on Policy_Profile__c(after insert, after update)
{
    //Since, we need two values from Policy_Profile__c to be populated on the new Product_Affected_Entry__c record.
    //So, taking a Map instead of list. Earlier, List<String> subAccNames=new List<String>();
    //Map of subAccountNames and Policy_Profile__c Record.</b>
    Map<String, Policy_Profile__c> subAccNames=new Map<String, Policy_Profile__c>();

    for(Policy_Profile__c newCont: Trigger.New) 
    {
        //Checking of the field is empty or not.</b>
        if(newCont.Products_Affected3__c!=Null && newCont.Products_Affected3__c!='') 
        {
            system.debug('newCont.Products_Affected3__c---->'+newCont.Products_Affected3__c);
            String temp=newCont.Products_Affected3__c.normalizeSpace();
            temp=temp.replace(']',''); //No need for this if comma seperated values as I have taken.
            temp=temp.replace('[',''); //No need for this if comma seperated values as I have taken.</b>

            //Iterate the number of values in the temp variable by slitting them by comma
            //add put them in subAccNames</b>
            for(String acctName: temp.split(','))
            {
                subAccNames.put(acctName.normalizeSpace(), newCont);
                system.debug('subAccNames !!! '+subAccNames); 
            }
        }
    }

    //Take a Map of Name and Record for holding Vendor_Product__c Name and Vendor_Product__c Record.</b>
    Map<String, Vendor_Product__c> subAccIdsByName=new Map<String, Vendor_Product__c>();

    //Iterate over the Vendor Product records and create a Map with Venfor Product Id as Key and Vendor Product Record as Value.</b>
    for(Vendor_Product__c subacc: [SELECT Id, Vendor__c, Name FROM Vendor_Product__c WHERE Name IN :subAccNames.keySet()]) 
    {
        //Putting record in place of Id, as value in the map.</b>
        subAccIdsByName.put(subacc.Name, subacc);
        System.debug('subAcc Name and ID='+subacc.Name +'Id='+subacc.id+'Vendor_c='+subacc.Vendor__c);
    }

//&nbsp;   //This will hold the Product_Affected_Entry__c records to be upserted.</b>
    List<Product_Affected_Entry__c> subs = new List<Product_Affected_Entry__c>();

    //Iterating over subAccNames Map.
    //No need to iterate again over Policy_Profile__c records as we have already taken the Policy_Profile__c record in the subAccNames Map.
    //Earlier: for (Policy_Profile__c newContract : Trigger.New)</b>
    for(String ref1: subAccNames.keySet()) 
    {
        //Iterate over the subAccIdsByName Map.</b>
        for(String ref2: subAccIdsByName.keySet())
        {
            //Match if the Name in the subAccNames Map is equal to Name in the subAccIdsByName Map.</b>
            if(ref1==ref2)
            {
                Product_Affected_Entry__c ssoc = new Product_Affected_Entry__c();
                ssoc.Policy__c=subAccNames.get(ref1).Id;
                //Access Vendor Product Id from the Map.</b>
                ssoc.Vendor_Product__c=subAccIdsByName.get(ref2).Id;
                //Access Vendor__c from the Map.</b>
                ssoc.Vendor__c=subAccIdsByName.get(ref2).Vendor__c;
                //Access Name from the Map.</b>
                ssoc.Policy_and_Product__c=subAccNames.get(ref1).Name+'~'+subAccIdsByName.get(ref2).Id;
                //Put the records in the </b>subs </b>list.</b>
                subs.add(ssoc);
            }
        }
    }

    upsert subs Policy_and_Product__c;
}
```

Comment: Does Product_Affected3__c contain a JSON array of strings? If so the cleanest way to parse it is to use `List<String> values = (List<String>)  JSON.deserialize(newCont.Products_Affected3__c, List<String>.class);`. If it is actually a multi-select picklist field splitting on ';' is the normal approach.

Comment: No - Product_Affected3__c is just a text field with values separated by a comma. It doesn't seem to have any problems with that because in the debug showing SECONDsubAccIdsByName shows it is properly querying each of the values and retrieving their Id,Vendor__c, and Name.

Comment: OK. I just noticed the bits of code checking for and replacing the square brackets that are array delimiters in JSON.

Comment: The brackets are placed there by a VF controller.

Comment: ... perhaps trying to achieve JSON syntax for the convenience of later processing code such a yours.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer to your question, but it's more than I can put in a comment.

I see the following with your code:

Below, you've just declared your map. It's empty. No need to follow it with a debug statement.

```
    //----> Take a Map of Name and Record, instead of Name and Id.
    Map<String, Vendor_Product__c> subAccIdsByName=new Map<String, Vendor_Product__c>();
    System.debug('FIRSTsubAccIdsByName='+subAccIdsByName);
```

This may be at the root of your problem. Strings are immutable and can't be reassigned to themselves after you perform an operation on them as below:

```
        temp = temp.replace(']','');
        temp = temp.replace('[','');
```

Finally there is this section of code below:

```
            integer tempnum=0;
            for(String productsonpolicy: all)
            {
            System.debug('************************temp'+temp);
                //----> Iterate over the subAccIdsByName Map.</b>
                for(Integer i=0; i<subAccIdsByName.keySet().size(); i++)
                {

                    System.debug('************************tempnumA'+tempnum);
                    tempnum = tempnum+1;

                    //----> Match if the Name in the productsonpolicy is equal to Name in the 
                    //subAccIdsByName Map

                    if(productsonpolicy==(new List<String>(subAccIdsByName.keySet()))[i])
                    {

                        System.debug('************************tempnumB'+tempnum);

                        ..........
                        ..........    

                        subs.add(ssoc);

                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm not certain what the purpose of `tempnum` in your code is, but I see where you're iterating it inside a for loop that's nested 2 layers deep. Why you're doing that is unclear to me.

It's also unclear why you iterate it at beginning of the nested loop instead of at the end of the loop. It would seem that you *might* be missing data that gets created or used the first time through although I don't see where the variable is used anywhere inside that section of code. That said, I can't help but question whether this should be nested within that loop, but instead perhaps within a loop that much further out if it needs to be iterated, and if so, located at the end of the loop its iterating.

**Edit**

I suspect the root of your problem could also be in this line:

```
         if(productsonpolicy==(new List<String>(subAccIdsByName.keySet()))[i])
```

In the above, `[i]` could be ignored as an iterator. The new list should be declared as:

```
new List<String>sbactIdsbyname = list<string>();
sbactIdsbyname.addAll(subAccIdsByName.keySet());
```

Once you've done the above, you can test it against list values of `[i]` in your if statement. In your current method, I suspect you're only testing it once.

Comment: I used the tempnum variable just to show me how many times it was iterating through the loops in the debug.

Comment: Then I suspect your problem lies within your string code.

Comment: Which part of the string code do you feel could be flawed ? Like I mentioned to Keith, it's not having a problem separating the values and querying the records they represent. I saw it retrieve the values in the debug which references SECONDsubAccIdsByName.

Comment: See my edit about adding your set to a list. I recommend you add a debug statement after each string method statement.

Comment: Which edits ? It says you edited my original post - and then there's the post you put up which has the code. I'm trying to figure out which changes you've made.

Comment: The edit to my post. Its in Bold at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I'm trying to figure out how to apply your suggestions but I think I'm out of my league here. I tried putting those two lines for the List sbactIdsbyName within the loop but am getting an unexpected token error. Sorry I'm so inept on this.

Comment: Declare you new list outside of any of your for loops or at the beginning of your trigger. Do the `addAll` before that loop starts (can do it after the original map is created that you get the keyset from). You then use the new list as part of your if condition as in `if(productsonpolicy==sbactIdsbyname[i]){` (using name of list from my post above). You could also use `string.valueOf(mapname.keyset([i]))` instead, but can't do the `new list` coding as you currently have it.

Comment: crm - thank you so much for all of your insight. Somebody else helped me with a solution and I just wanted to post it here in case you were curious. The front part of this whole project is in a VF page for the object which creates a picklist with dynamic choices which are child records of another object based on the user's selection of a different field. When put all together it's really great stuff, something just about every SF developer could find a use for. I'm guessing you would be able to write it yourself, but if you would like to see it anyway I could show it to you.

Comment: Thanks for the update Zoom. Good to hear you got it sorted. Thanks for letting me know. I see where you've posted your final code.